# Searching the full-text of the files in the respository in svn?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Is there any way to search the full text of all the revisions (or just a specific revision) of a subversion repository?

I mean I know that tools like Google Code search must do this somehow (or at least index the text), I was just wondering if there was any way to do this with just a subversion client.

Comment: Do you mean to search through all the revisions for a specific phrase, not just one revision?

Comment: @nickf All revisions or a specific revision.  Thanks nickf.

Comment: Whoa, somebody just upvoted this?  I feel bad for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [SupoSE](http://supose.soebes.de/wiki/supose). This is a Java based approach to do real searching within a complete Subversion repository.

Or check the whole list of Subversion [Links/Books/Tools](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/www/links.html?p=900404).

Comment: The tools seems to be abandoned, and it is unavailable - 404 not found.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a little heavyweight setup-wise, but [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) is an invaluable tool for my dev team. We trigger updates by [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) after every build and we instantly search 1M+ lines

Comment: +1 interesting. The set-up seems to be indeed quite complex, too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing magic is required.  Just check out the repo, then do grep -r (or however you normally search files).  If you want to search an old version of the repo, do:

svn export -r revID /path/to/checkout /export/to

then search /export/to.  Of course, there may be more optimal ways, but this is probably good enough for your purposes.